# Can't download file - SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number

Tags: bash, curl, wget

I'm trying to download files from noaa ncep site, but I get this error

```
usuario@wrf:~/wrf_data/GRIB$ curl https://ftp.ncep.noaa.gov/data/nccf/com/gfs/prod/gfs.2019020700//gfs.t00z.pgrb2.1p00.f000 -sslv3
* About to connect() to ftp.ncep.noaa.gov port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 140.172.138.66... connected
* Connected to ftp.ncep.noaa.gov (140.172.138.66) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number
* Closing connection #0
```

I could download the files until Tuesday, I used this..

```
curl -O $FILEDWLT

The version
curl --version
curl 7.21.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.21.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8o zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.15 libssh2/1.2.6
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz
```

I tried with `wget` and get similar error. I used a debian machine (squeeze), its old but for now is all I have.
Someone can guide me please?
Best Regards
Carina

Comment: It's possible that the error is due to the other side, and their TLS not working on their end. Can you run the same command using `-v` or `--verbose` as an argument, so more information can be output?
Also, the file you linked is accessible by `wget`, but not with `curl` on my end.

Comment: Connected to ftp.ncep.noaa.gov (140.172.138.66) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [data not shown]
* error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
* Closing connection #0
curl: (35) error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Comment: wget -v https://ftp.ncep.noaa.gov/data/nccf/com/gfs/prod/gfs.2019020700//gfs.t00z.pgrb2.1p00.f000
--2019-02-07 11:27:07--  https://ftp.ncep.noaa.gov/data/nccf/com/gfs/prod/gfs.2019020700//gfs.t00z.pgrb2.1p00.f000
Resolviendo ftp.ncep.noaa.gov... 140.172.138.66
Connecting to ftp.ncep.noaa.gov|140.172.138.66|:443... conectado.
OpenSSL: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
No se pudo establecer la conexión SSL.

Comment: In both cases the SSL connection fails at the handshake, which makes me think it's an error on the remote end. Can you curl another `https` website or an `ftp` server correctly?

Comment: You're right.  wget --no-check-certificate --auth-no-challenge -v --debug https://ufpr.dl.sourceforge.net/project/hfs/HFS/2.3k/hfs2.3k.zip. I download the file without a problem and with curl too. curl -O -v https://ufpr.dl.sourceforge.net/project/hfs/HFS/2.3k/hfs2.3k.zip

Comment: I'd suggest contacting the website owners and forwarding this information. It might help them resolve the issue faster and/or offer you another way of fetching the files you need.